# Make GET parameters pretty in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewrite on a search result page but am having a bit of trouble getting it to work.

The scenario is:

www.website.com/products?keyword=&asset=the-asset-name

I'd like it to be formatted:

www.website.com/products/the-asset-name?keyword=

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. I've dabbled with both Htaccess and $wp_rewrite but to no avail.

Comment: I'm not a wordpress guy but isn't that a built-in feature? https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Are you hosting the site, wordpress, or some other hosting service?

Comment: @BrianCohan We are hosting the site ourselves.

Comment: @VolkerK The Wordpress permalink settings only cover pages and posts. I'm dealing with some custom post types here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress should be able to do this from the admin settings. If you are hosting on your own server, make sure that apache or whatever software you are using to serve web requests has modRewrite or something similar enabled.

[Pretty permalinks are available under](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module

Hiawatha web server with UrlToolkit support enabled.

Microsoft IIS 7+ web server with the URL Rewrite 1.1+ module and PHP 5 running as FastCGI

Microsoft IIS 6+ using ASAPI_Rewrite (free for single-site server, $$ for multi-site server)

Microsoft IIS 6+ using Ionic ISAPI Rewriting Filter (IIRF) (free for single-site or multi-site server)

Lighttpd using a 404 handler or mod_rewrite (see See Also)

Once you have that, assuming apache, make sure your directory has permissions to control the server by putting the following in your host definition. I don't know what the other IIS and the like require, but the following is straight out of what I have for my wordpress site.

```
<Directory /path/to/your/files/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: The permalink settings in the admin only cover pages/posts/categories. I've got a custom post type where 'asset' is a parameter attached to the post.

Comment: Updated some documentation from wordpress's codex, make sure you have the appropriate module enabled. I was bashing my head on this problem for a while and found out that I didn't have modRewrite enabled. Then I spent another long while bashing it until I realized that my virtualhost didn't have permissions to use the .htaccess file.